# Filtering objects from external array to create a list, using jQuery AJAX and $.grep

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I don't know the best way to explain this... I'm just learning AJAX and this is a real challenge for me.

Basically, I want to store a big array of items (objects) inside a json file and then, dynamically generate multiple lists *depending on some filters*; each array object's property works as a filter.
For this I'm using jQuery `$.grep()` function.

The problem is that I'm might be missing something, because although the json file is successfully loaded, the "filtering" is not being done.

Look at my first try (without ajax), **it works** just like I want:
http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/p2hgrk8h/2/

But if I try to do the same, using AJAX, then **it doesn't work**:
http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/6a2Lzof6/

Here's the jQuery code (with comments):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Frondor/422b87c6b64ab9927c9b/raw/d5ae5b4d6dd03c083549609d2b45edc7b2ed726f/gistfile1.json',
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function (items) {

            console.log(items); //check the array is loaded

            var hand = $.grep(items, function (obj) { 
                //filter only items with hand:0, hand:1 and rf:1
                return obj.hand <= '1' && obj.rf === '1'; 
                //at least the first item should match this, doesnt work
            });

            //create new array with filtered items
            var lista = $.map(hand, function (item) {
                console.log(item);
                return '<li>' + item.name + '</li>';
            });

            $("#manoderecha ul").empty().html(lista);
        }

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="manoderecha">
    <ul><li>This item shouldn't be displayed</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, returned data isn't a valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/), keys should be valid strings. Wrap the keys with quotes, then you are fine.

Comment: @code-jaff I did followed instructions from this message: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21954524#21954524
But anyway, I wrapped the keys with quotes like you say, and it still doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/6a2Lzof6/1/ the json file is being loaded but it is not "returned" any filtered objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are two things:

The json on your fiddle is broken, so is parsed as text, and the second one you should parse as json the result, if you don´t on the call, you should do on the succes

```
  console.log(items)
   var itemsJSON= JSON.parse(items)
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9oL8r0dr/14/